# file upload: success function is not working in online version

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have following codes in my PHP classes:

```
...
success: function(response){

  if(response==='Successs'){
    $('.'+input.id + ' .info_danger_text').html('');
    $('.'+input.id + ' .progress-bar').removeClass('active progress-bar-striped ').addClass('progress-bar-success')
    console.log(response);
  }

  else if(response==='sizeError') {
    $('.'+input.id + ' .progress-bar').removeClass('active progress-bar-striped ').addClass(' progress-bar-danger');
    $('.'+input.id + ' .info_danger_text').html('Илтимос, хажми 2мг дан кичик бўлган файлни юкланг');

  }
} ,
......
```

and

```php
$fsize=$_FILES[$key]['size'];
  if($fsize > 2097152){
    echo "sizeError";
    return;
  }
  else{
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$key]['tmp_name'],$name )){
      echo 'Successs';
    } else {
      echo 'fail';
    }
  }
}
```

This code works in the local version of my web application. However, it is not working in the online version. It is not returning a size error (for a file which size is larger than 2MB). How can I fix this issue?

Comment: what's not working? Try adding an `alert(response)`statement to `success` function.

Comment: first check <?php phpinfo(); ?> and check the value of post max size and then 
try changing post_max_size & upload_max_filesize  parameter in your php.ini file or try ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M'); and restart your server and check.

Comment: `input.id` ? Are you targeting `ID` of the element, if yes then selector should be `#`[ID selector] :)

Comment: Improved code formatting for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you added java-script library into your page. If not please add it.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep this, before your code,

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '64M'); 
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');
```

OR make changes related to these attributes in your php.ini file as

```
post_max_size 64M
upload_max_filesize 64M
```

And then restart server, if apache,

then run

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

From terminal.

It should work.